# Picking from list randomly according to Pareto Principle

Tags: java, random, distribution

I have a `List<T>` and try to randomly pick items according to [Pareto Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), so first 20% items will be picked 80% times, and 80% remaining items will be picked 20% times. So far I have a simple implementation:

```
static <T> T pickPareto(List<T> list) {
    int n = list.size();
    int first = n * 0.2;
    return rnd.nextFloat() < 0.8            
           ? list.get(rnd.nextInt(first))                // pick one of first 20%
           : list.get(first + rnd.nextInt(n - first));   // pick one of remaining 80%
}
```

It works well, but picks items according to a distribution which is a *step function*.

Does anyone know how to select items according to distribution which is  *smooth function* (maybe not exactly Pareto, but holding 20/80 property)?

Comment: when you say _step_, what is the value of `list.size()`?

Comment: @tod I meant this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function. Sorry for bad English

Comment: did `nextFloat` instead of `next` not solve your problem?

Comment: @tod it was just a typo. What I'm trying is to switch from step to smooth distribution function.

Comment: to achieve that you would probably have to repeat your experiment several times... you can also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). Moreover, i think your question maybe better answered at cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time on research, I discovered that this problem can be reduced to a problem of finding the function, which applied to a function producing uniform random distribution (`.nextFloat()` for example), results desired distribution.

Such function `f(x)` must meet all following conditions:

1. `f(0) = 0`
2. `f(x) → 1` for `x → 1`
3. be non-decreasing, better strictly increasing, on interval `[0, 1)`
4. be smooth on interval `[0, 1)`
5. `f(0.8) = 0.2` -- **condition of 80/20 Pareto Principle**, or, in common, `f(p) = 1 - p`

Finally, I succeeded with such function. It can be:

*f(x) = (x<sup>a</sup> + 1 – (1 – x)<sup>1/a</sup>) / 2,*
*a = log<sub>p</sub>(1 – p)*

Here argument `p ∈ (0, 1)` means exactly what it means in condition 5: it is an adjustment parameter showing how resulting distribution will differ from uniform. For example, if `p = 0.8` then `f(0.8) = 0.2`. If `p = 0.5`, then  `a = 1` so function collapses to `f(x) = x`.

Chart for `p = 0.8`:

[image]

So the method to pick from list will look like:

```
public static <T> T pickRandomly(List<T> list, float p) {
    if (p <= 0 || p >= 1.0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    double a = Math.log(1.0 - p) / Math.log(p);
    double x = rnd.nextDouble();
    double y = (Math.pow(x, a) + 1.0 - Math.pow(1.0 - x, 1.0 / a)) / 2.0;
    return list.get((int) (list.size() * y));
}
```

---

For example, picked 1000 times from list of 10 integers, `p = 0.8`:

```
0: 646
1: 153  // 0 or 1 occured 799 times
2: 60
3: 57
4: 32
5: 26
6: 18
7: 7
8: 1
9: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `nextFloat()`, it will give you the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed float value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

```
return rnd.nextFloat() < 0.8            
       ? list.get(rnd.nextInt(first))                // pick one of first 20%
       : list.get(first + rnd.nextInt(n - first));   // pick one of remaining 80%
```

Also, I presume `rnd` is float.